# Why does Chrome 58.0.3029.81 (64 Bit) cause ViewExpiredException on log in?

Tags: google-chrome, jsf, glassfish

On Thursday (2017-04-26), I began seeing the following error when I logged into my application using my Authenticator JSF page.

> [#|2017-04-30T15:18:51.649-0500|WARNING|glassfish
>   4.1|javax.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=30;_ThreadName=http-listener-1(2);_TimeMillis=1493583531649;_LevelValue=
>   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet
>   Faces Servlet threw exception
>   javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException:
>   viewId:/security/Authenticator.xhtml - View
>   /security/Authenticator.xhtml could not be restored. at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:212)
>
> at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>
> at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:123)
>
> at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)

My Authenicator.xhtml page is backed by a Authenticator.java class with the following header.

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Authenticator implements Serializable {
```

During my research, I discovered the following:

- I am able to log into my application using Chrome 58.0.3029.81 one time after restarting the computer running the GlassFish 4.1.2 server.  If I log off, I will get the above error on every future log in attempt. (This is a weird one.)
- I can log in using Internet Explorer
- I can log in using Chrome versions older the 58.0.3029.81.
- I can log in using Chrome 57.0.2987.132 on my Android telephone
- I can log in using Chrome 58.0.3029.81 if I change the javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD variable in my web.xml file from server to client.

Why would Chrome 58.0.3029.81 kill the Authenticator view resulting in the ViewExpiredException?

As requested, I analyzed the network traffic and determined that Chrome 58.0.3029.81 sends two additional Get requests during the Authenticator.xhtml display process than Chrome 57.0.2987.133 sends.

Chrome 57:

- GET /webapp/security/Authenticator.xhtml HTTP/1.1
- GET /webapp/security/RES_NOT_FOUND HTTP/1.1
- GET /webapp/security/RES_NOT_FOUND HTTP/1.1
- POST /webapp/security/Authenticator.xhtml HTTP/1.1

Chrome 58:

- GET /webapp/security/Authenticator.xhtml HTTP/1.1
- GET /webapp/security/RES_NOT_FOUND HTTP/1.1
- GET /webapp/security/RES_NOT_FOUND HTTP/1.1
- GET /webapp/security/RES_NOT_FOUND HTTP/1.1
- GET /webapp/security/RES_NOT_FOUND HTTP/1.1
- POST /webapp/security/Authenticator.xhtml HTTP/1.1

Since I don't know why Chrome sends the RES_NOT_FOUND gets in the first place I don't know if sending two extra is a bad thing but it seems to be related to GlassFish 4.1.2 not being able to reconnect to the Authenticator view.

Could this be an issue with my Authenticator.xhtml page or is it a Chrome 58/GlassFish 4.1.2 issue?

The following is a comparison of the Post information:

Chrome 57 Post

```
POST /webapp/security/Authenticator.xhtml HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 205
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://localhost:8081
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://localhost:8081/webapp/security/Authenticator.xhtml
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: JSESSIONID=4067aa3d0df7f2bc26b8200a8c4a;
modena_expandeditems=j_idt32%3Awelcome-menu

authentication-form=authentication-form&authentication-form%3AuserName=XXX&authentication-form%3Apassword=XXX&authentication-form%3Aj_idt93=&javax.faces.ViewState=-4577625721740212982%3A4298605796688550126
```

Chrome 58 Post

```
POST /webapp/security/Authenticator.xhtml HTTP/1.1  
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 204
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: http://172.24.1.125:8081
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://172.24.1.125:8081/webapp/security/Authenticator.xhtml
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: JSESSIONID=4089ef02f0bca32d331de1f5404f

authentication-form=authentication-form&authentication-form%3AuserName=XXX&authentication-form%3Apassword=XXX&authentication-form%3Aj_idt93=&javax.faces.ViewState=3383766421781608154%3A6418504070036764787
```

The only difference that I see is that Chrome 57 appended "; modena_expandeditems=j_idt32%3Awelcome-menu" after the JSESSIONID.

Comment: Debug network traffic, find the differences...

Comment: The only obvious difference is that Chrome 58.0.3029.81 send 2 additional get requests during the Authenticator.xhtml display than Chrome 57.0.2987.133.    I edited question to show the details.

Comment: Look at the differences in the posts... Is e.g. the session-id cookie missing? If so, that explains the view-expired exception and that would not be a problem if you switch to client-side statesaving.

Comment: The Posts look very similar except that Chrome 57 added some extra information.  I edited the question with the Post comparison.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion.  I posted the comment before I edited the question.  You should be able to see the post comparison now.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you look at the two 'quoted' texts of the posts above (better to add 'code' tags in it to since it formats things better), I see two 'links' that are fundamentally different. In 57, everything is localhost, in 58 some are '172.24...' Might be a fundamental difference, check the Chrome releasenotes for changes related to this (and how to (maybe) fix it). And are you sure you are doing this from the same client? Or two clients?

Comment: I downgraded the Chrome on my development computer where GlassFish runs so that I could debug this issue.   The Chrome 57 logs are from Chrome 57 running on the GlassFish server and the Chrome 58 logs are from Chrome running on another workstation.  I don't think this makes a difference because the external Chrome worked fine until I upgraded it to 58 and the local Chrome did not work until I downgraded it to 57.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be an issue with version 2.1.1 of the PrimeFaces premium theme called Modena and PrimeFaces 6.  During HTTP analysis, I noticed that Chrome 57 sent 2 RES_NOT_FOUND requests and Chrome 58 sent 4 RES_NOT_FOUND requests.  This was a known issue with Modena 2.1.1 as documented in the following PrimeFaces Modena Forum issue:

[PrimeFaces Modena Forum Issue](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=45381&p=142036&hilit=RES_NOT_FOUND#p142036)

During each RES_NOT_FOUND request, the JSESSIONID would change and something about the additional 2 changes in Chrome 58 would break the link between JSESSION and ViewState.

Upgrading Modena to version 2.1.3 eliminated all the RES_NOT_FOUND requests and resolved the ViewExpired issue.

Comment: Wow.... Great catch... Upvote from me. Would not have expected this. Makes me curious to why this RES_NOT_FOUND eventually breaks it... Maybe the 'number of views' that are cached is to little... or... Maybe @BalusC has some insight